# Fingerprint stopped working after password changed

Tags: windows-10, authentication, fingerprint

Usually, I log in as 'normal' user. I also have an administrator account, for which I have set up a fingerprint to log in.

If I need to run some application with elevated privileges, and Windows asks for an admin account, I just need to swipe my admin-finger, and the application starts.

This stopped working some time ago, after my admin password was reset (I had forgotten it because I never had to type it in ;-). Now, when I swipe, the fingerprint is recognized, because the login dialog reopens with the admin username filled in, and a message saying *The username or password is incorrect*.

I have already reset my admin fingerprints, but this did not change anything.

It looks like the old password is still stored somewhere and connected to this fingerprint, although I have no idea if it really works like that.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to change the password locally (on my laptop). Apparently, resetting a password by our IT department does not update the fingerprint + password combination.